# How do I store a dict/list in a database?

Tags: python, database, string, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary full of nested stuff, how do I store that in a database, as a string? and then, convert it back to a dictionary when I'm ready to parse?

Edit: I just want to convert it to a string...and then back to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best, under your stated conditions:

```
import cPickle
   ...
thestring = cPickle.dumps(thedict, -1)
```

the `-1` ensures the most efficient serialization and produces a *binary* string (arbitrary string of bytes).  If you need an *ascii* string (because e.g. some Unicode transcoding is going to happen and you can't switch the field's type from, say, `TEXT` to `BLOB`), avoid the `-1`, but you'll then be less efficient.

To get the dict back later from the string, in either case,

```
thenewdict = cPickle.loads(thestring)
```

Comment: this will work with utf-8, right? (Just, default strings, I mean.)

Comment: `utf-8` is fine in the keys and values, but there is no guarantee that `thestring` will respect `utf-8` encoding (most likely it won't: it's just bytes!).  If that's a problem you must omit the `-1` argument (there's a reason why "do the fastest, most effective, and most concise serialization" is _not_ the default but requires that explicit `-1`... actually there are multiple reasons, but this is one of them;-).

Comment: For safety reasons, I'm going to avoid the -1 :) and just do normal. I don't care about speed anywayz.

Comment: If you don't care about speed, size, and functional completeness (ability to pickle objects whose classes define `__slots__` but not `__getstate__`), the old, legacy protocol (what you get by avoiding the `-1` is fine).

Answer (score 4):

Options:

1) Pickling

2) XML

3) JSON

others I am sure.  It has a lot to do on how much portability means to you.

Comment: I just want to convert it to a string...and then back to a dictionary.

Comment: If you don't care about portability, then go for the pickling (http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) functionality. Go for the "cpickle" variant which is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use some serialization/deserialization from pickle module ?

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of serialization methods out there, JSON is readable, reasonably compact, supported natively, and portable. I prefer it over pickle, since the latter can execute arbitrary code and potentially introduce security holes, and because of its portability.

Depending on your data's layout, you may also be able to use your ORM to directly map the data into database constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

- use a standard serialization format (json, xml, yaml, ...)

  - pros: you can access with a any language that can parse those formats (on the worst case you can write your own parser)
  - cons: could be slower to save and load the data (this depends of the implementation mostly)
- use cPickle:

  - pros: easy to use, fast and native python way to do serialization.
  - cons: only python based apps can have access to the data.